# php ajax checkbox always checked

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I have a form to display quotes based on data recieved/checked.

It's a non-refreshing page, so it uses ajax get the submit click and then it sends data to php file.

The main problem is that the checkboxes are ALWAYS checked, and are echo'ing "ON". I need the checkboxes to work as normal, unchecked by default and then when user clicks on it, and submits the form they will actually be checked.

These are the checkboxes

```
<div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="lighting" id="lighting"><font color="#2C3E50" value="">Lighting</label></font>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="heating" id="heating"><font color="#2C3E50" value="">Heating</label></font>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="dancefloor" id="dancefloor"><font color="#2C3E50" value="">Dancefloor</label></font>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="internaldressing" id="internaldressing" value=""><font color="#2C3E50">Internal Dressing</label></font>
    </div>
```

I tried removing value attribute, I tried adding checked attribute. literraly nothing helps.

This is part of the AJAX file:

```
    var dataString = 'eventtype=' + eventtype + '&peoplecount=' + peoplecount + '&location=' + location + '&eventdate=' + eventDate + '&lighting=' + lighting + '&heating=' + heating + '&dancefloor=' + dancefloor + '&internaldressing=' + internaldressing;


    $.ajax({  
    type: 'POST',  
    url: 'process.php',
    data: dataString,
    success: function(data) {
        if( data == '0' )
            alert( 'Błędne dane logowania!!!' );
        else
             $('#results').html(data);

    }  
}); 
        event.preventDefault();
```

And then my PHP looks like this.

```
if(isset($_POST)){

        // Total price of quote. 
        $price = 0;
        // Prices of extras. 
        $lighting_price = 0;
        $heating_price = 0;
        $dancefloor_price = 0;
        $internaldressing_price = 0;

        // Stage I VARIABLES
        $eventType = $_POST['eventtype'];
        $peoplecount = (int)$_POST['peoplecount'];
        $location = $_POST['location'];
        $eventDate = $_POST['eventdate'];

        // Stage II VARIABLES 
        $lighting = $_POST['lighting'];
        $heating = $_POST['heating'];
        $dancefloor = $_POST['dancefloor'];
        $internaldressing = $_POST['internaldressing'];

        // If there are less than 70 guests then make base price 650. 
        if($peoplecount < 70){
            $price = $price + 650;
            $lighting_price = 75; 
            $heating_price = 150;
        }

        // If there are between 71 and 130 guests then make base price 950.
        if(($peoplecount >= 71) && ($peoplecount <= 130)){
            $price = $price + 950;
            $lighting_price = 150;
            $heating_price = 250;
        }

        if (isset($_POST['lighting'])){
            echo "IM TICKEED!!!!!!!";
        }

        if (isset($_POST['heating'])){
            echo "IM TICKEED!!!!!!!";

        }

        echo $eventType . "<br>";
        echo $peoplecount . "<br>";
        echo $lighting . "<br>";
        echo $heating . "<br><br>";
        echo $price;

        }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: and the checkbox is ?

Comment: Edited the main post to add checkboxes.

Comment: Instead of if (isset($_POST['lighting'])){ try if (!empty($_POST['lighting'])){

Comment: Can you please show us what the content is for $_POST on those variables related to the checkboxes?

Comment: I tried doing !empty and that didn't work either.   @devlincarnate what do you mean content? The html part, php and js That's all i've got.  When $_POST in php, they echo as "ON".

Comment: For example, show us the result of `var_dump($_POST['lighting']);`

Comment: var_dump outputs this -    STRING(2) "ON"

Comment: ok, so if that's not correct, then the problem is with the code that's producing the POST variables, not with what you're doing once you received the POST variables.  How is lighting populated in POST?  What is the value in the database?

Comment: p.s.  you should tag me when you give you response so I am alerted.  @user3488750

Comment: What about uncheck the checkboxes with js on page load, based in your comment: "The main problem is that the checkboxes are ALWAYS checked, and are echo'ing "ON". I need the checkboxes to work as normal, unchecked by default and then when user clicks on it, and submits the form they will actually be checked."

Comment: Not using any database for this, I don't want to store any data really, just calculate, display them and flush them on the go. It might the issue with the ajax post, since that is sending the data to php right? I have no idea what though and how to fix that. The boxes look unchecked on the actual form btw, and checking them doesn't change anything. @devlincarnate

Comment: @user3488750 - so do `console.log(dataString);` and show us the result

Comment: @devlincarnate sorry, for a late answer - had to do some shopping after work.   Anyways heres the output of console log  eventtype=Wedding&peoplecount=120&location=&eventdate=undefined&lighting=on&heating=on&dancefloor=on&internaldressing=          - It all just seems to show "ON" just like in echo in php, I'm wondering if there is a way in ajax to specify whether the checkbox provided in data is actually checked or not and only then send the data to php?? I think this doesn't work because of the ajax thing, I mean if it was only html and php it would work right? I need it non-refresh though

Comment: Regarding how dataString is composed, where is `lighting` defined and assigned?  That is the source of your problem.  `'&lighting=' + lighting` is showing `&lighting=on`.  You need to track down where that "on" is coming from.

Comment: This is your complete JS file?

Comment: @devlincarnate The variable is var lighting = $("#lighting").val();   and then that goes to     var dataString = 'eventtype=' + eventtype + '&peoplecount=' + peoplecount + '&location=' + location + '&eventdate=' + eventDate + '&lighting=' + lighting + '&heating=' + heating + '&dancefloor=' + dancefloor + '&internaldressing=' + internaldressing;

Comment: @cmnardi no, this is just a function in my js file, but anything else has nothing to do with it. the variables are declared as var lighting = $("#lighting").val();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing first. Please add value attribute to your checkbox. They will be passed as the value to your url.

Please check whether the checkbox is selected or not. Try putting the checked pseudo selector.

```
$('#lighting:checked').val()
```

If the checkbox is not checked then it will give you undefined value so please check that condition while assigning value.

```
 var lighting = ($('#lighting:checked').val() === undefined )? null : $('#lighting:checked').val();
```

The above line won't effect code that much but it's a good to have thing.

While assigning it to your datastring variable you can check whether it is null or undefined or not and append the string like that. If the variable has a value then append it to the datastring variable which you will pass as ajax url.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I used this to if($_POST['variable'] == "null") to check that info whether it has been checked or not and it's working this way, so I picked your answer. I'm just wondering are there any downsides of using this method?

Comment: Well actually I think you should not put that condition like that. If a checkbox is not selected you should not append it to url. You can  create your data url based on which checkboxes are selected. Then send your request on the url. The unchecked checkbox won't pass to your requested url and you can use empty() or isset() to check the values...
If you didn't get what I said and want my answer to be elaborated I can do that to show you. ^_^

Comment: Ah okay sorry, I read your comment again and I get it now, so basically if they do return null then do not include them in the dataString at all and if they are checked then include them. I'm only wondering how would I do this though, i'm not so good in js and I'm beginner in php

Comment: @JugaIK , it sure did, thanks a lot. I made a simple if statement for each of the variables and it works. It probably would have been more efficient doing this in a loop? hmm

Comment: well yup. To do that assign same class for every checkbox on which you want to assign the value. And then use $.each() for assigning values. You might need to adjust your values accordingly as you want the key of url dynamic here.You can  assign a data- attrib to determine which checkbox is for which url key. like for lighting you can do something like value='1' data-name='lighting' and in $.each loop get data('name') to get the value to be assigned.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript ajax syntax, Place this code inside the ajax request success function

```
document.getElementById('lighting').checked = false;
```

do this for other checkboxes by changing id name

Comment: I already tried looping all the input types checkbox and making them false, unfortunately that didn't work too.

Comment: Sometimes the javascript code that you are wrote in <heade> </head> Tag. Don't do that. You should be include your javascript code at up to </body> tag.

Comment: getElementById('id') property has become to null when inside the <head></head> tags because it's read first before your html dom read.

Comment: Do you understand? or still having problem? but don't worry I'm still help you.

Comment: The javascript is not in the head, so this shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: Oh... just well, I'm checked your script, in your script has some errors , what is eventtype , peoplecount etc, variables in your dataString variable. for what? that are not defined!

Comment: This is just a part of my code, it's not all.. The variables are defined as:  var lighting = $("#lighting").val();